# Charts/Graphs on Logentry server

Tags: charts, logentries

Is it possible to fetch charts which show on logentries server using API ?
I have a requirement where we need to show such usage charts on a custom application, am wondering if I can get the charts directly from logentries ?

If that is not possible, is it possible to get filtered/plotted data using which we can generate our own charts ?

Comment: Is this export functionality available through APIs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be doable with the Export function for charts. Note that some search queries are not exportable at the moment

https://logentries.com/doc/shareable-dashboards/#share_dashboard

Comment: Hi Stephen ..yes that is possible. I was wondering if this is possible through an API, so I can include this functionality in an independent client application.

Answer (score 0):

Checked with Logenteries team, charts api are not there in production as yet.